# Social Network Analysis - Influence Maximization

Tags: timestamp, social-networking, sna

I would like to find the k most influential nodes for maximizing the information diffusion. I select the nodes based on high degree and nodes belonging to different communities. I would like to increase the priority of nodes having recent timestamp value. How can I consider timestamp value to increase the selecting probability of a node?

Answer (score 0):

Is your question actually: how to quantify a timestamp? Maybe it helps you to kind of turn it into a score. For example: (node_timestamp - oldest_known_timestamp) / (now - oldest_known_timestamp) would give you a score from 0 to 1 where 0 is the worst and 1 is the best score

Comment: Thank you, can you suggest me how to get the social graph dataset with edge timestamp value. I have seen in SNAP, Infochimps, Gephi datasets etc but I couldnt find dataset I need.

Comment: Sorry i have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: Thx.. I have found huge no. of datasets here http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/networks.. Anyone need datasets can refer here :)